# ActiveRecord.Where is not returning a list of objects in test environment (mini test)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having an issue with one of my tests. I have a user model that has a activated(boolean) column. When I try to find all the users that are activated for display in my index action via:

```
def index
    @users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: params[:page],
                                                  per_page: 10).order('name ASC')
end
```

The code works fine when rendering the view in development ENV. However when I run the code in the test ENV using:

```
rails console test 

User.where(activated:true)
```

it returns ActiveRecord::Relation [], which is breaking one of my tests.

I also tried running the above where method using rails console (Dev ENV) and got a list of User models returned to me.

Can someone explain why the code doesn't work in the test ENV?

** As an update I use fixtures for my test data such as:

I use fixtures such as

```
<% 30.times do |n| %>
user_<%= n %>:
  name:  <%= "User #{n}" %>
  email: <%= "user-#{n}@example.com" %>
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true,
  activated_at: Time.zone.now
<% end %>
```

Comment: How did you create data for your test?

Comment: hi @taitrantuan , I use fixtures. I added how the fixtures are created (to the question above) in the users.yml file.